# How to automatically generate rowspan using php

Tags: php, loops, html-table

In this code everything is perfect except that I could not generate rowspan in the Internal Grade cell. this line `<td rowspan="<?php echo $cols;?>">` hides the bottom border while I expect to span the rows every time the code generates rows. Thanks for your input and sorry for using `mysql()` function. I am newbie.

```
<?php $cols=mysql_num_rows($grds);  ?>
<table>
<?php do{ ?>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
//This hide the bottom border
<td rowspan="<?php echo $cols;?>">Internal<br />Grades</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;<?php echo strtoupper($row_grds['grade_name']); ?></td>  
<td><?php echo strtoupper($row_grds['igrade']); ?></td>
<?php } while ($row_grds=mysql_fetch_assoc($grds)); ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

The output is like below:
[output is here](http://i60.tinypic.com/33c9kld.jpg)

The code generated by php is:

```
<table>
   <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td rowspan="1">&nbsp;</td>// A
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;RHYMES</td>  
  <td align="center">B</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>//B
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;CONVERSATION</td>  
  <td align="center">A</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to merge A and B

Expected output is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;Internal<br /> Grade</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;RHYMES</td>  
    <td align="center">B</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;CONVERSATION</td>  
    <td align="center">A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show what it generates? The actual HTML output would be easier. Start by putting your closing `</tr>` **inside** the `while` loop.

Comment: @outvande, I will create an image of and update the question.

Comment: Not an image, just post the actual HTML

Comment: What I posted here is the actual html code.

Comment: The HTML what it looks like after PHP rendered it.

Comment: I have just update what you said. Thanks.

Comment: You know what `rowspan` and `colspan` do right? Your `colspan` seems pointless as the `td` in both rows have it. `rowspan="2"` on the bottom row will not work either.

Comment: The html code that you provided has the bottom row: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmEhk. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So how I do it. I want to generate rowspan on the second column every time the code generates new rows which of course depends on the number of rows return from mysql database.

Comment: @Gasim, I mean bottom border.

Comment: You put the rowspan once, lets say in the first column. Check out the usage of rowspan. You are adding rowspan twice for the same column: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve (i updated the code): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmEhk

Comment: Yes you are right, but I want the number of rowspan to be generated by php from the number of rows returned from mysql

Comment: @Gasim, I think you have mistaken my question. I am generating rows from database using php. So I did not put any more <td></td> but php generates them. So how do I get rid of this extra row in order to get it right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this:

```
<table>
<?php $row_grds = mysql_fetch_assoc($grds); ?>
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td rowspan="<?=$cols;?>">Internal<br />Grades</td>
     <td colspan="2">&nbsp;<?=strtoupper($row_grds['grade_name']);?></td>  
     <td><?=strtoupper($row_grds['igrade']);?></td>
    </tr>

<?php while ($row_grds=mysql_fetch_assoc($grds)): ?>
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td colspan="2">&nbsp;<?=strtoupper($row_grds['grade_name']);?></td>  
     <td><?=strtoupper($row_grds['igrade']);?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Its not perfect but you are using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, which on its own is not perfect either :D

Comment: Thanks very much. But your code is not working it returns just one row and one column only. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to do. Check out the output of this code (I don't have a database on me, so I simulated it using arrays): http://ideone.com/F6PXAt;